# How do I make this delete button on the blog comment section work?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have tried many different things to make this button work, so I am wondering if there is one thing I am not doing correctly.
Error Message from laravel:

> No error the delete just doesnt happen

Here is the code:

Laravel PHP Posts Controller Comment Snippet:

```
function save_comment(Request $request,$slug,$id){
        $request->validate([
            'comment'=>'required'
        ]);
        $data=new Comment;
        $data->user_id=$request->user()->id;
        $data->post_id=$id;
        $data->comment=$request->comment;
        $data->save();
        return redirect('news/'.$slug.'/')->with('success','Comment has been submitted.');
    }
    function delete_comment(Comment $comment,$slug,$id)
    {
        $comment->delete();
        return redirect('news/'.$slug.'/')->with('success','Comment has been Deleted.');
    }
```

web.php routes comment snippet:

```
Route::post('/save-comment/{slug}/{id}',[PostsController::class,'save_comment']);
Route::delete('/delete-comment/{slug}/{id}', [PostsController::class, 'delete_comment']);
```

HTML blade snippet:

```
@if(Auth()->user()->id == $comment->user_id)
<span style="float: right;">
                     <form 
                        action="{{url('delete-comment/'.Str::slug($post->title).'/'.$post->id)}}"
                        method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method('delete')
                        

                        <button
                            style="background-color: #333; color: #fff; margin: 5px; padding: 1px;"
                            type="submit">
                            Delete
                        </button>

                    </form>
</span>
@endif
```

Comment: I could be wrong but so far as I know, a html form can only send a GET or a POST.  Using ajax could be a potential alternative

Comment: The form specifies POST though, so it's unclear how you could be getting a message complaining about use of a GET. Are you sure it's this form which generated the error??

Comment: I am about to update the post with the most recent development. You see my confusion.

Comment: Please see now @ADyson

Comment: [Please investigate first](https://www.google.com/search?q=crsf+@method(%27Delete%27)+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `Route::post` so `@method('Delete')` does not make sense

Comment: @mplungjan Please see now

Comment: I see nothing called "comment" sent to the server. Only a button

Comment: Which line supposedly generates this latest error. I see no $comment variable declared inside the code anywhere. Did you mean to use $data instead perhaps?

Comment: the button/route is set to send the function 'delete_comment' to the server, how can i define comment in the function

Comment: DB::table('comments')->where('id',$comment->id)->delete();

Comment: Please see now @mplungjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the comment in the delete URL, so how could it possibly know which one to delete?

For either request, you don't need the slug as this is presumably part of the associated post model. For deleting, you don't need the post at all since it's a property of the comment. For saving, you should get the post using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding).

For both routes, you should be using [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes) and not constructing URLs manually.

Try something like this:

```php
function save_comment(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $request->validate([
        'comment'=>'required'
    ]);

    $comment = new Comment(["comment" => $request->comment]);
    $comment->user()->associate($request->user());
    $comment->post()->associate($post);
    $comment->save();

    // this should also be a named route with a parameter
    return redirect('news/' . $post->slug . '/')
        ->with('success', 'Comment has been submitted.');
}

function delete_comment(Comment $comment)
{
    $post = $comment->post;
    $comment->delete();

    return redirect('news/'. $post->slug . '/')
        ->with('success','Comment has been Deleted.');
}
```

Update your routes accordingly:

```php
Route::post('/save-comment/{post}',[PostsController::class,'save_comment'])
    ->name("comment.post");
Route::delete('/delete-comment/{comment}', [PostsController::class, 'delete_comment'])
    ->name("comment.delete");
```

And your form:

```html
@if (Auth::user()->is($comment->user))
<form method="post" action="{{ route("comment.delete", $comment->id) }}">
@method("DELETE")
@csrf
...
</form>
@endif
```

Comment: Everything works except the redirect

Comment: As I said, I'm assuming the slug is a property of the `Post` object. If it's not, change the code as needed. Really you should have a method like `Post::getUrl()` to generate the URL to a post for you.